# css li background problem

Tags: css

I have a vertical menu with a background. I need to shift the background to the right and in the center from top but an unable to do this.  http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=b0b07d2

```
ul.nav 
{
 margin:0; background-position:center;  background-image: url(../images/nav_bg.gif);font-family: "Century Gothic"; height:40px; padding-left:30px;
} 
ul.nav  a{ 
height:19px;color:white;display:inline-block;font-family:Century Gothic,Arial;font- size:14px;padding:8px 20px 0 ;text-decoration:none !important;vertical-align:middle;
}
ul.nav  a:hover
{
color:white;display:inline-block;font-family:Century Gothic,Arial;font-size:14px;height:19px;background-image: url(../images/nav_over.gif);
background-position: center top;background-repeat: no-repeat;text-decoration:none !important;vertical-align:middle;
}
* html ul.nav a
{
color:white;display:inline-block;font-family:Century Gothic,Arial;font-size:14px;height:19px;text-decoration:none !important;vertical-align:middle;
}
 ul.nav  a.highlight{
color:white;display:inline-block;font-family:Century Gothic,Arial;font-size:14px;height:19px;text-decoration:none !important;vertical-align:middle;
}
ul.nav li{
    display: inline;
    color:#FFF;
    background-image: url(../images/white_dotline.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:right center;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:8px 1px;
    font-family:"Century Gothic";
    height:19px;
    [height:19px;
    height:20px;]/*Google Chrome, Opera and newer Safary 4+*/
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The horizontal and vertical position is controlled by the `background-position` property. The first number defines the **horizontal** position and the second the **vertical** position.

Words can be used for horizontal such as `left`, `right` and `center` and for vertical it is `top`, `bottom` and `center`.  Absolute positions can be used also, such as *pixels* or *ems*, as well as *percentages*.

For example:

```
background-position: right top; /* positioned to the right and the top */
background-position: 100% 0; /* positioned 100% to the right and zero from the top (the same as above) */
background-position: 50px 200px; /* positioned 50px from the left and 100px from the top */
```

Answer (score 0):

You have specified a single value for the background position, which means that it's used for horisontal positioning, and the vertical positioning is set to 50%. You should specify two values to control both positions. Example:

```
background-position: left center;
```